# Trying to add simple constraint but got this error message

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints

I'm trying simple experiment just to try how I can add constraints into an object. So, I create just a single UIView (yellow coloured) with vertical space constraint = 200 from storyboard like this :

[image]

here's my interface file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *screenView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *container;

@end
```

and I want to programatically modify Vertical Space Constraint of `_container` by having this code on my `viewDidLoad` :

```
NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:_screenView
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:_container
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                   multiplier:5
                                   constant:15];
[_container addConstraint: myConstraint];
```

but when I run it into simulator, I got this error message :

```
> 2013-09-19 05:48:26.488 container[6036:c07] *** Terminating app due to
> uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install
> constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from
> outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal.
> constraint:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7168860 UIView:0x7168b50.width ==
> 5*UIView:0x7169360.width + 15> view:<UIView: 0x7169360; frame = (0 0;
> 0 0); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7168bb0>>'
```

what did I do wrong? thank you...

UPDATE : here's what I mean with _container 
[image]

and here's _screenView
[image]

Comment: What are _container and  _screenView?

Comment: @rdelmar : hi, thanks for your comment... please check my update to see what are _container and _screenView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that _screenView is the superview of _containerView, so your constraint should be added to it, not _containerView. Also, you say, " I want to programatically modify Vertical Space Constraint of _container by having this code on my viewDidLoad", but what you're doing is adding a completely different constraint (a width constraint) instead of modifying the one you have. If you want to modify the vertical spacing constraint, you can make an IBOutlet to it, and modify it's constant value in code.

Comment: you're right about NSLayoutAttributeWidth. I should use : NSLayoutAttributeHeight. but, I've change constraintWithItem:_container, toItem:_screenView and [_screenView addConstraint: myConstraint]; and I still got error on my debugger console

Comment: here's error message : 2013-09-19 06:31:01.915 container[389:c07] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

Comment: @RobertHanson, that's because you've added a width constraint that conflicts with the constraints you have now. It looks like you have 0 length spacing constraints from _containerView to the sides of the _screenView. If you're going to add a width constraint, then you need to remove one of those horizontal spacing constraints. You can do that by making an IBOutlet to it, and removing it with removeConstraint:.