# I'm in purpose of hiding UIPickerView below the screen using constraints, can I ignore this debugger message?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to hide UIPickerView below the screen, in this case 3.5 inch display. after learning about constraint value, finally I know what number should I put for `NSLayoutAttributeTop`.

here's my complete code :

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:_pickerView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.view
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                  multiplier:1.0f
                                  constant:416.f];

[self.view addConstraint:constraint];
```

and when I run into my iDevice it works like I expected, except... the debugger console.. it gives me this message :

```
2013-09-19 12:34:01.850 Constrain2[3546:c07] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x75490d0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x715a2f0(416)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7159950 V:[UIPickerView:0x715a030(216)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x71597c0 V:|-(416)-[UIPickerView:0x715a030]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x715a2f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x715a7a0 UIPickerView:0x715a030.bottom == UIView:0x715a2f0.bottom>"
)
```

when I changed the constant value into = 200.f which taken from 416 (superview) - 216 (uipickerview), debugger console is clear. no message there.

is it error message or just a warning? can it be ignored? is it possible to hide that UIPickerView below the screen without having that message appear on debugger console?

it seems that message won't appear when UIPickerView placed properly in its position. that is constant: 200.f

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not ignore that -- the system will try to fix it by removing a constraint, but I don't know if it will always remove the same one, and give you the result you want. You appear to be adding a constraint that conflicts with one you already have (I commented on that same problem in my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883664/trying-to-add-simple-constraint-but-got-this-error-message/18883834#18883834) previous question of yours). When you add a new constraint in code, you need to remove one (or  more) that you made in IB that will conflict with it. However, to do what you're trying to do, you shouldn't even be adding a new constraint, you should be modifying the one you made in IB. From the error message it looks like you have a constraint from the bottom of the picker to the bottom of its superview (with 0 length). You should make an IBOutlet to that constraint (lets call it bottomCon for example), and then just modify its constant parameter in code:

```
self.bottomCon.constant = -216;
```

In any case, if you're making a constraint to a view that's near the bottom of the screen, you should make the constraints to the bottom, not the top like you do in your question. If you make the constant to the top, it won't be correct in a different screen size or orientation.

Comment: thanks for your answer, professor. it makes me clear about constraint now... I really appreciate it...

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

```
_pickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

before you add the constraint.

Comment: thanks for your answer, bro.. but I still see same message on debugger console...